# Visual Studio This application is in break mode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am doing this:

```
public async Task Update(Entity input)
{
    ValidateUpdate(input);
    await UpdateAsync(input);
}

public async void ValidateUpdate()
{
    // Some Logic
    int adminCount = await _dbContext.AdminEntities
        .CountAsync();
    if(adminCount == 0)
    {
        throw new AppUserException("The tenant must always have at least one admin.");
    }
}
```

And when I hit the exception visual studio shows it to me, but then when I click on "continue execution" VS shows me a page "The application is in break mode". If I click again on "continue execution" VS just stops running the application.
When I throw the same exception in other parts of my app it simply gets returned as response of my HTTP request. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, it is because I made my method async without changing the `void` return type to `Task` and I didn't await the validation.
This is the fixed example:

```
public async Task Update(Entity input)
{
    await ValidateUpdateAsync(input);
    await UpdateAsync(input);
}

public async Task ValidateUpdateAsync()
{
    // Some Logic
    int adminCount = await _dbContext.AdminEntities
        .CountAsync();
    if(adminCount == 0)
    {
        throw new AppUserException("The tenant must always have at least one admin.");
    }
}
```

I was in a rush and forgot to check the basics. I hope this will at least help someone else or my future self when I inevitably make the same mistake again.

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Yeah, I had to wait couple of days before I could accept the answer. Even if it is was my own. I just marked it as answered, thanks for the reminder!